# Python - How to loop until site is down using requests and threads

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop, request, monitoring

So what I want to do is that I want to make a sorts of monitor a website that pick ups a random number. Before it does it needs to requests to the website to see whenever it is valid or not. When it is live it will generate random numbers 1-100 and I want it to check every random 3-6 second and then print again the number and repeat until the website is down.

What I have tried to do is following:

```
def get_product_feed(url_site):
    thread = url_site
    password = False #We start by giving a false/true value
    while not password: #If it is not True then we do the for loop

            available = False 
            while not available:
                try:

                    checkpass = requests.get(thread, timeout=12) #We requests the site to see if its alive or not

                    if ('deadsite' in checkpass.url): #If it contains etc deadsite then we enter the while True

                        while True:
                            contcheck = requests.get(thread,timeout=12) #We make new requests to see if its dead.
                            if ('deadsite' in contcheck.url): #if it is, then we sleep 3-7sec and try again

                                randomtime = random.randint(3, 7)

                                time.sleep(randomtime)

                            else: #If its not containig it anymore then we send the bs4 value

                                available = True

                                bs4 = soup(contcheck.text, 'lxml')
                                return bs4
                                break

                    else: #If its having either of them then we send instant.
                        bs4 = soup(contcheck.text, 'lxml')
                        return bs4
                        break

                except Exception as err:
                    randomtime = random.randint(1, 2)
                    time.sleep(randomtime)
                    continue





def get_info(thread):
    while True:
        try:
            url = thread

            resp = requests.get(url, timeout=12) #We requests to the website here
            resp.raise_for_status()
            json_resp = resp.json() #We grab the json value.

        except Exception as err:
            randomtime = random.randint(1,3)
            time.sleep(randomtime)
            continue

        metadata = json_resp['number'] #We return the metadata value back to get_identifier

        return metadata


def get_identifier(thread):

    new = get_info(thread) #We requests the get_info(thread):

    try:
        thread_number = new
    except KeyError:
        thread_number = None

    identifier = ('{}').format(thread_number) #We return back to script

    return identifier



def script():
    url_site = 'https://www.randomsitenumbergenerator.com/' #What url we gonna use
    old_list = []

    while True:
            for thread in get_product_feed(url_site): #We loop to see through get_product_feed if its alive or not
                if get_identifier(thread) not in old_list: # We then ask get_identifier(thread) for the values and see if its in the old_list or not.

                        print(get_identifier(thread)
                        old_list.append(get_identifier(thread)
```

I added a comment to make it easier to understand what is going on.

The issue I am having now that I am not able to make ***get_identifier(thread)*** to run until the website is down and I want it to continue to print out until the website is live til it dies and that is my question! What do I need to do to make it happen?

My thoughts was to add eventually threads maybe that 10 threads are checking at the same time to see if the website is dead or not and give back the value as a print but I am not sure if that is my solution for the question.